# End with without with compile error. I am comparing two string

Tags: vba, excel

```
Function CompareTwo(txt As String, txt2 As String, _
            Optional delim As String = ";") As String
    Dim a, b
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
            For Each a In Split(txt, delim)
                For Each b In Split(txt2, delim)
                 If Trim(a).contains(Trim(b)) Then .Add Trim(a), Nothing
                Next b
            Next a   
    If .Count > 0 Then
    CompareTwo = Join(.keys, delim)

        End With
End Function
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: ...however it's probably a quick fix anyway.  if I understand what you're trying to do, change: `If Trim(a).contains(Trim(b)) Then` to `If instr(Trim(a),Trim(b))>0 Then`   . . .   Also the `IF` that's split on 2 lines should be put together on the same line: `If .Count > 0 Then CompareTwo = Join(.keys, delim)` (or otherewise keep it as-is and add an `End If` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an End If.

```
Function CompareTwo(txt As String, txt2 As String, _
            Optional delim As String = ";") As String
    Dim a, b
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
            For Each a In Split(txt, delim)
                For Each b In Split(txt2, delim)
                    ' what is 'contains' ?
                    If Trim(a).contains(Trim(b)) Then .Add Trim(a), Nothing
                    ' maybe this is better
                    If cbool(instr(1, Trim(a), Trim(b), vbtextcompare)) Then .Add Trim(a), Nothing
                Next b
            Next a   
            If .Count > 0 Then
                CompareTwo = Join(.keys, delim)
            end if  '<~~ here

        End With
End Function
```